# ElasticSearch query with query inputs

Tags: elasticsearch

i have an index of data in ElasticSearch

```
{
  "name":"john",
  "type":"main",
  "address":"26, pression road, next to maha maul, Atlanta, USA",
  "description":"i am from atlanta. i a need of help on elastic search. my name is john wosniak"
},
{
  "name":"shailesh",
  "type":"other",
  "address":"c-401, greenfield road, next to cyber city, mumbai, india",
  "description":"i am from mumbai. i dont need. my name shailesh"
},
{
  "name":"pratik",
  "type":"main",
  "address":"c-116, parmar society, john main road, andhari, India",
  "description":"i am from andhari. i a need of help on elastic search. my name is pratik doshi, i am good friend of john"
},...
```

i want to search using some advance query such that it searches `"type":"main"` and `"john"` in rest of all the fields.

for now i am using the query

```
{
    "query_string" : {
        "fields" : ["name", "type","address", "description"],
        "query" : "main john*"
    }
}
```

it is not giving me desired result as per my requirement.

hope i have explained clearly. thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you look at [bool query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html)?

You can achieve desired results with [boosting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_boosting_query_clauses.html)

```
 {
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "type": {
              "query": "main",
              "boost": 10
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "query": "john",
            "fields": [
              "name",
              "address",
              "description"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: your answer works fine for one of my requirement. just a quick run-up. i could not find/make a suitable solution by Boolean query for a different type of requirement. i needed all the results having `"type": "main"` at top and rest all below it based on `"multi_match": {
            "query": "john",`. can you also help me with that.

Comment: do you want both conditions to be true or just any one of the two?basically your requirement is **AND** or **OR**?

Comment: `OR` Condition but `"type":"main"` results should be on top

Comment: Is there any way to boost certain string and get those many results in top of the search. In the above example i take all the results where i find john and those many johns who are having type: main comes on the top of the result and rest below it